# Logging in a Python script is not working: results in empty log files

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I had a script with logging capabilities, and it stopped working (the logging, not the script). I wrote a small example to illustrate the problem:

```
import logging
from os import remove
from os.path import exists


def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.WARNING):
    # Erase log if already exists
    if exists(log_file):
        remove(log_file)
    # Configure log file
    l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='w')
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    l.setLevel(level)
    l.addHandler(fileHandler)
    l.addHandler(streamHandler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_logger('log_pl', '/home/myuser/test.log')
    log_pl = logging.getLogger('log_pl')
    log_pl.info('TEST')
    log_pl.debug('TEST')
```

At the end of the script, the file test.log is created, but it is empty.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `setup_logger` function specifies a (default) level of `WARNING`

```
def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.WARNING):
```

...and you later log two events that are at a lower level than `WARNING`, and are ignored as they should be:

```
log_pl.info('TEST')
log_pl.debug('TEST')
```

If you change your code that calls your `setup_logger` function to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_logger('log_pl', '/home/myuser/test.log', logging.DEBUG)
```

...I'd expect that it works as you'd like.

See the [simple example](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example) in the Logging HOWTO page.

Comment: the OP is just *****, now i cant write the same problem because it would be marked as duplicate, i had the same problem but my logging level is already correct

Comment: I'm having the same issues as @greendino