# Logging from a Python script is not writing to the file when using TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging

The following logging lines in a Python script is not writing a debug message to the log file when using TimedRotatingFileHandler, but it is writing a logging exception message:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%a %d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')

buet_logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')
blogger = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, 'midnight', 1)
blogger.suffix = '%a_%Y_%m_%d.log'
blogger.setFormatter(formatter)
blogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
buet_logger.addHandler(blogger)


buet_logger.debug("Bluetooth start")
```

Comment: You didn't set the level on the logger. You need to set the level on both the handler and the logger.

Comment: yes thanks @blues you right.                                                                             changed to bluet_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python logging not working: results in empty log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084756/python-logging-not-working-results-in-empty-log-files)